# How do I conditionally get items from DB using specific value in React(Next.js)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, conditional-statements

In my database, there are files. every single file has 'IS_DELETE' row, which shows whether this file is deleted or not.

If 'IS_DELETE' row of a file is **0, it means it is not deleted** by the writer of the post.

If 'IS_DELETE' row of a file is **1, it means it is deleted** by the writer.

However, I use a GET request to render the items.

*I made the code so that you can see it clearly. I might mispelled!*

```js
test = () => {

const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

const getDetails = async () => {
  await get(`URL`)
  .then((res) => {
     setFiles(res)
  })
} 

useEffect=(() => {
  getDetails()
},[])

return (

<>

  files.map((file) => (
   <div>
     {file}
   </div>
))

</>

)}
```

With this code, I render every file, although some files have '1' in their IS_DELETE row.

**I am wondering whether I can conditionally get the items from DB
or
I get every file and filter my array using a particular function.**

FYI, I get the files in this format.

```js
[
{PK:1, NAME:'Hello.jpg', IS_DELETE: 0}
{PK:2, NAME:'Nice.jpg', IS_DELETE: 1}
{PK:3, NAME:'To.jpg', IS_DELETE: 0}
]
```

Thank you. I'm not good at English. So please be understandable.

Waiting for your wisdom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot modify the response you get from server unless it specifically has an endpoint to do so. It's like sending a letter and awqiting the response - you cannot make the response diffeent unless your recipient allows you to send a letter with a specific request (eg. 'give me only non-deleted items'), but if you're not in charge of the server, the only thing you can do is indeed filtering the items you get in response.

```
const getDetails = async () => {
  await get(`URL`)
  .then((res) => {
     const filtered = res.filter(file => file.IS_DELETE === 0);
     setFiles(filtered);
  })
}
```

Comment: Wow. This works really fine!

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the parameter is_deleted in the url concatenate with the main one

{url}?is_deleted=0

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand what you're talking about :( Maybe you can add some explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database you are using, it is possible to do so. For example, in an SQL database, you could do `SELECT * FROM files WHERE IS_DELETE != 0`

But you can also do it in the frontend as shown below:

```
const getDetails = async () => {
  const res = await get(`URL`);
  setDetails(res.filter(file => !file.IS_DELETE));
}
```

Comment: I think this is the same way! I had to use filter(). Thank you sigc. simple & clean!

Answer (score 0):

my idea is to pass parameter in the url as query string and in the server side you get the value and put it in the database query

```
test = () => {

const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

const getDetails = async () => {
  await get(`URL?is_deleted=0`)
  .then((res) => {
     setFiles(res)
  })
} 

useEffect=(() => {
  getDetails()
},[])

return (

<>

  files.map((file) => (
   <div>
     {file}
   </div>
))

</>

)}
```